# Cultivation manhua/manhwa in which the main character goes on adventures with his female masters

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I remember reading this quite a while ago. The main character is put in his astral form goes on adventures with his female masters (he has more than one female master). He learns different cultivation paths from different female masters. Later on, he returns to his body and travels to one of his master's sects and joins it. Causing a lot of comedic havoc such as killing and eating one of the elders carps and so on. I read it between 2019-2020 or it might have been 2021 sorry this isn’t specific. The art style is somewhat similar to “Beyond Myriad Peoples/ Above ten thousand people” or “I’m actually a cultivation big shot”
And as a note it’s not “I return from Heavens and World”