Cultivation manhwa where the main character has female masters
I know the title isn't much to go off on, but from what I can remember, the main character was betrayed by his ex and was forced into a cage after having his martial arts broken and his physique stolen where his spirit travelled across the world with a female master. Later on, he finally was able to return to his body and get a really strong physique. Afterwards, he leaves to go to visit his other female masters' sects and joins as a student. One chapter I remember was when he cooked and ate one of the elders' spirit "chicken." The art style is similar to Above Ten Thousand People.

Sounds similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/280964/cultivation-manhua-manhwa-in-which-the-main-character-goes-on-adventures-with-hi but there's no answer there either.
